# How to change log source in Nomad?

Tags: docker, consul

I have a CLI application which runs on Nomad,

```
task "create-cli" {
    driver = "docker"
    config {
        image = "cli-app:local"
        tty = true
        auth_soft_fail = true
    }
}
```

Now on Nomad web UI, if I pull up logs, I see CLI artefacts that one would see when attaching to that container.
But I have this file separately stored in that container `logs/logs_app.log`, how can I configure nomad to show me logs from that file in the web UI.

P.S. I didn't find tags for `nomad` and this doesn't let me create new tags with my reputation.